# How to group list of entities by day using timestamp field?

Tags: java, spring

I have an entity `class`:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "reports")
@Getter
@Setter    
public class Report {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(name = "reg_number")
private String regNumber;
@Column(name = "imei")
private Long imei;
@Column(name = "speed")
private double speed;
@Column(name = "altitude")
private double altitude;
@Column(name = "longitude")
private double longitude;
@Column(name = "latitude")
private double latitude;
@Column(name = "timestamp")
private long timestamp;


}
```

I have stored these entities in MySQL db. These entyties are being deleted every day if entity is older than 14 days.

The question is, how can I group them by day? I want something like `HashMap<Date, List<Report>>` as a result. That would be:

24.06.20 : List of reports in that day.

23.06.20 : List of reports in that day.

22.06.20 : List of reports in that day.

and so on.